# Every time i click this button, app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I added a button, and i added from the widgets, then added these two sets of code

```
android:onClick="first"
```

to the xml file and

```
public void first(){
    System.out.print("poly Second");
}
```

to the java file

after i click this button, the app crashes

the rest of the code is the same as a blank activity

ps. i am very new to android studio, java and programming in general

Comment: `public void first(View v)`

Comment: You need to inflate the Layout your Button sits in. Also what's the error log says?

Comment: sorry i'm not understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method first(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'